# PWM SQL database unable to create table

Tags: sql, database, pwm

I am trying to setup a PWM server but when I get to the Database Remote Connection I get the error below which appears to be the sql database unable to create a table. I have reviewed the logs and they state that the connection to the SQL database was successful. When I go to the SQL database and manually try to add a table it also fails.

> unable to initialize database: exception initializing database service: 5051 ERROR_DB_UNAVAILABLE (error creating new table PWM_META: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'value TEXT )' at line 3)